# Android App with access to some library dependencies using Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm creating an Android App. All the business logic is in a library that I'm adding to my app project importing its AAR file.

But this library has some compiled project dependencies I'd need to use from the app, but don't know how.

LIBRARY PROJECT

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile(name: 'lib1', ext: 'jar')
    compile project(':lib2')
```

I'm exporting this library as **mobile-release.aar**.

APP PROJECT

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'mobile-release', ext:'aar')
```

How can I access from my app project to those lib1, lib2 from mobile-release?

I tried adding

```
compile(:mobile-release:lib1)
```

without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the short solution is to include your library aar file as module dependency in the application project, and then add the library dependencies

```
//in app projet
dependencies {
    //....
    compile project(':mobile-release') {
        dependencies {
             compile(name: 'lib1', ext: 'jar')
             compile project(':lib2')
        }
    }
}
```

there are other solutions like publish you library to a local/remote repository, or create a function in the library gradle file that takes the jar dependencies and add them to the generated aar

Comment: When trying this I get: Error:(70, 0) Project with path ':lib2' could not be found in project ':app'. It looks like it's searching the lib dependencies in the app project, not in the library project... so they are not found.